# What is the purpose of the Composition (Object Composition) in C++

Tags: c++

I am not quite sure about the purpose of the Composition (Object Composition).

In the Composition, a class can have an instance of other class.

```
class CInner
{
public:
   CInner();
   virtual ~CInner();
   void Func();
};

class COuter
{
public:
   COuter();
   virtual ~COuter();
   void Func();
private:
   CInner m_inner; // Composition
};
```

Is the Composition used to subdivide a large class into composites of small classes?

Are there any example showing that the Composition is useful compared to when the Composition is not used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data aggregation is one use, though that could be accomplished with structs, in C.  However,  aggregation vs. composition, in Object-Oriented Programming (OOP), is viewed as the difference between "using" and "owning" specialized types (or sub-objects), respectively.  OOP excels at solving problems that require this angle of thinking.

As Daniel Daranas mentioned "A car has an engine."  Furthermore, that engine has parts that all have different properties.

A functional car will also have a transmission, a radiator, a gas tank, axles, wheels, etc.  All of which are "objects" that the car makes use of, which in turn have parts that they make use of.  This is called [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

The combination of these components is called [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).  However, as I mentioned earlier, the relationships between these objects must be one of ownership, in that the object containing the other objects can be seen as "owning" those objects.  If this is not the case, it is referred to as object aggregation, which implies that the outer object merely "uses" the inner object.

One of the biggest reasons for using encapsulation and object composition like this is because it helps to separate modes of thinking from one big, complex problem into multiple, smaller problems, that can all be viewed separately, so they become less daunting.

More specifically, object composition helps us to abstract the idea of a single object that is made up of multiple, simpler parts.

For example, if you tried to put an entire 800 page textbook in one sentence (with the same amount of text), it would be VERY difficult to read and understand.  There would be nowhere to break up your thoughts and give concepts time to sink in.

However, if you break up a long text into sentences, paragraphs, sections, chapters, and possibly even units, if it seems appropriate, it can become a lot easier to understand where certain subjects begin and where they end, what parts are more related to what other parts, and so on.

However, without organizing those sentences into paragraphs, those paragraphs into sections, those sections into chapters, etc., you will have lost the benefits of the encapsulation.  The proper organization would be best described as object composition.

Abstraction by encapsulation and object composition are two of the most powerful and important aspects of OOP.

Here's some links for info on OOP and what it's good for:

[OOPS : Abstraction, Encapsulation, Inheritance, Polymorphism](http://pankajtiwarii.blogspot.com/p/oops-abstraction-encapsulation.html)

[OOP - Data encapsulation](http://en.kioskea.net/contents/421-oop-data-encapsulation)

[Chapter 20. Object-Oriented Programming Principles (OOP)](http://www.introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/read-online/chapter-20-object-oriented-programming-principles/)

[Java - Encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

[OBJECT ORIENTED AGGREGATION](http://atomicobject.com/pages/Aggregation)

[Composition Over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Composition != encapsulation. Your answer makes it seem like they are the same thing.

Comment: I apologize.  I should clarify that, you're right.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: That should be better.  Thanks again.  Sometimes I get going on explaining something and completely forget the original question I was answering T_T

Comment: Thank you very much about the explanation.